# Gradle build IO Exception

Tags: java, gradle, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem with Gradle. When i run my app with Intellij, it works perfect. When i try to run it with Gradle i get IO Exception. I think that it may be problem with BufferedReader, or path.

I have tried use different ways to read file, and most of them works good with intellij, but I had same problem with gradle

```
  try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("KlingonsName.txt").getFile());
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((name = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                bfr.readLine();
                names.add(name);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I would like to read file and add names to list, but i get IO Exception(File not Found) when while loop is invoked.

Comment: `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` find resources from the classpath. Either you have a different classpath when running from Gradle, or the resource doesn't get packed into the proper place.

Comment: How do you run your app in Intellij? Could you post your project structure? I want to know where `KingonsName.txt` is stored.

Comment: Why are you not using [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)?

Comment: I used getResource() because i had problem with tests, so i changed it to find file path by name. I think that it have different paths with gradle, but still i thought that it will find that file. 

I just use run button to run app or tests, when I use Intellij., but when i change it to Gradle build, i have this problem.

I tried many solutions, and I will try NIO.2. I am beginner so I just don't know yet every solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem, because this file was in module Data, but it should be out of modules, because few modules used this file. But I fix problem different

```
try {
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    InputStream i = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(("KlingonsName.txt"));
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));

    String l;
    while ((l = r.readLine()) != null) {
         names.add(l);
    }
    i.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
 }
```